# I get email from filter subscription once a week instead of once a day

Tags: bug, email, filtering, subscription

I manage a few filter subscriptions at https://stackexchange.com/users/44871/marcel-st%C3%B6r?tab=subscriptions. All of them are set to 'every day'. Yet I only get an email about once a week listing issues created several days back. Is that a bug on your end or did I missing some important flag?

Comment: Hmm. Might be the same as or at least related to this issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318767/daily-subscription-email-sent-out-10-days-after-the-question-was-posted.

Comment: True, looks veeery similar. Pity my earlier search for such an issue didn't turn this up. In my case it really looks like StackExchange was "collecting" issues for several days until it eventually notified me.